# Assembly Register Arithmetic?

Tags: c, assembly, pointer-arithmetic

When you are using both the MOV and LEA instructions in assembly, what does it really mean when someone writes:

```
   mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], 0x80484c 
   lea eax,[ebp-40]
```

Specifically, when they write the information in the brackets []. I know that lea moves addresses and mov moves content, but when they are computing the addresses in lea or mov, how does that actually work? Is it the same as pointer arithmetic in C?

Comment: `Is it the same as pointer arithmetic in C?` - No, it isn't. A comprehensive answer can be found in any decent x86 assembly documentation/book, and freely available around.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no real memory access in `lea` : it merely calculates the address of the operand, and stores it. Compilers sometimes use it to perform unsigned arithmetic - though not in this particular case, it seems.

Comment: Not only can comprehensive answers be found in assembly documentation, you can find lots of very comprehensive and clear answers here with a quick search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lea` does not *move* addresses, it **computes** the effective address and stores the resulting address into the destination register.  Address computations are performed in machine language with regular arithmetic, not C pointer arithmetic.

```
lea eax,[ebp-40]
```

subtracts `40` from the value in register `ebp` and stores the result in register `eax`.

```
mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], 0x80484c
```

Computes the destination address by adding `4` to the value contained in register `esp` and stores the value `0x80484c`, the integer `8407116`, as a 32 bit integer occupying 4 bytes at that address, least significant byte first.

Answer (score 3):

`lea` just calculates an expression and saves it to variable. It doesn't actually do anything with memory or memory addresses even through it is named 'load effective address'.

For example `lea eax,[ebp-40]` means `eax = ebp - 40`.

It can be used to calculate expressions which would otherwise take several instructions, for example:

```
lea eax, [8 * eax + ebx + 10]
```

calculates `eax = 8 * eax + ebx + 10` with one instruction.

On the other hand `mov`, when used with `[...]`, read/writes something from/to memory, so it's a bit like using C pointers.

```
mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], 0x80484c
```

This saves 32-bit unsigned integer (`DWORD`) value `0x80484c` to memory location `esp + 4`, i.e. same as following pseudo-C:

```
*((uint32_t*)(esp + 4)) = 0x80484c;
```

Comment: So could you say that every register starts out without any bits/bytes in it, and in order to move values into those registers, you have to add bytes to those registers? So if I wanted to move a 32 bit int into register EAX, I would have to say: mov DWORD PTR [EAX+4], (32 bit int)?

Comment: @JohnConradGeenty No. CPU registers are just internal variables of the CPU. For example `eax` is 32-bit register and will always contain some 32-bit value exactly a 32-bit variable would. (Google about X86 assembly registers to learn more.)

Comment: @JohnConradGeenty To move value into register, you use `mov eax, (32 bit value)`. I edited my answer to mention that only with `[...]` will `mov` access memory.